# Is there a hotkey to reverse the case of the selected text in the Delphi 10.2 Editor?

Tags: delphi

It is very annoying when the CapsLock pressed unintentionally and I realize that the text I just typed is in the reverse case.
Is there any hotkey to reverse the case of the selected text in the Delphi 10.2 Editor? And maybe for the other cases (upper, lower, capital, camel, uncapitalCamel).

MartynA answered this question and I have to realize that the hotkey mapped to this function (<kbd>Ctrl-O U</kbd>) is not a trivial one. So another question articulated in me : is there any way to customize the hotkey mappings? As I saw the Options dialog does not make it available. (Or I just could not find it)

Comment: No, there is no simple way to customize them except writing a keybindings expert. But I intend to write an expert that lets you change and save all shortcuts available directly from the IDE.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It would be very kind of you Rudy! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-O U</kbd> see http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys

If you are prepared to write an IDE add-in, you can do whatever you like in terms of changing case.  F.i. GExperts has its own Change Case, under Editor Experts and the source is available so you could look up how to do it.  GExperts also modifies the IDE's Key Mappings dialog under Tools | Editor Options so you could look up how to do that, too.

Comment: They named it "Toggles case". I would not have known it as "Reverse case" by my English. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any way to customize the hotkey mappings of the Editor? (for example : registry value modification) I does not find something like this in the Options/Editor settings. This is not a trivial combination compared to the number of times it could be useful.

Comment: @Bitman Yes, see http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2010/06/creating-editor-key-bindings-in-delphi.html

Comment: It is a surprisingly complex task compared to the solution of the NetBeans Editor. :O There is a graphical editor for this feature. I just thought that Delphi has a solution like that, or a property file/registry value to store this settings. It seems to me a very inflexible and useless solution.

Comment: @dummzeuch I asked that toggle the case of the selected text, not just the current character. And for this case the answer is very useful.

Comment: GExperts has a Change Case editor expert, which allows to select the kind of capitalization one wants to have. Default keyboard shortcut is Shift+Alt+C, not really that convenient either.

Comment: Toggle Case is utterly useless since (at least in my installation) toggles the case of the current character only. For that I have to press Ctrl+O + U, which is thee key strokes. Typing the character with the desired case is Del + <Character> or Del + Shift+<character>. Oops, it toggles the case of the selected text too.

Comment: @dummzeuch:  Fwiw, Toggle Case as per my answer works fine in D7...D10.2 under Windows 10 64-bit April 18 edition.

Comment: 20+ years using Delphi, and I didn't know that one! I use gexperts instead